# Android Webservice Boolean Check

Tags: android, xml, web-services, boolean

I am new to Android and I am working on determining if a stream is live or not. I have a preexisiting file that does that (http://www.calvaryccm.com/ServiceTimes.asmx/IsServiceTime). This is what it returns when the stream is inactive:

`<boolean xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">false</boolean>`

When the stream is active it returns this:

`<boolean xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">true</boolean>`

Does anyone know of a simple way to just check the boolean values? If so will you please provide source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reeeaaally ugly, but very simple solution:

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.calvaryccm.com/ServiceTimes.asmx/IsServiceTime");
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        byte buff[] = new byte[256];
        int len = is.read(buff);
        String response = new String(buff, 0, len);
        if (response.contains("true")) {
            System.out.println("!!! It's TRUE !!!");
        } else if (response.contains("false")) {
            System.out.println("!!! It's FALSE !!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("!!! Server/connection error !!!");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

A proper solution would would parse the result as XML file:

```
        DomHandler dom = new DomHandler(); // custom subclass of DefaultHandler
        SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
        parser.parse(is, dom);
        is.close();
        // extract info from dom
```